# Understanding proof that symmetric matrix is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, proof-explanation

[This text](http://maecourses.ucsd.edu/~mdeolive/mae280a/lecture11.pdf) gives a short proof that a symmetric matrix is diagonalizable.

> If the symmetric matrix $A$ is not diagonalizable then it must have
>   generalized eigenvalues of order $2$ or higher. That is, for some repeated
>   eigenvalue $λ_i$ there exists  $v\ne 0$ such that
>   $$(A − λ_iI)^2
> v = 0, \ \ (A − λ_iI)v \ne 0$$
>   **But note that**
>   $$0 = v^∗
> (A − λ_iI)
> ^2v = v^∗
> (A − λ_iI)(A − λ_iI)v \ne  0,$$
>   which is a contradiction. Therefore, as there exists no generalized eigenvectors of order $2$ or higher, $A$ must be diagonalizable.

The text defines $v^*=\bar{v}^T$. I am having trouble understanding the proof starting from "But note that...".

In particular,

(a).  I don't understand what role $v^*$ is playing here.

(b). I also don't understand how they know that $v^∗(A − λ_iI)(A − λ_iI)v \ne  0$ in order to make this contradiction.

Comment: it is $v^∗(A − λ_iI)(A − λ_iI)v=w^*w=\|w\|^2>0$, you forget to add the last $v$ in your expression. Note that $A-\lambda_i I$ is also symmetric for real $\lambda_i$

Comment: You seem to be saying that $(A − λ_iI)(A − λ_iI) \ne 0$. But how do you know that? (question b). Does that have something to do with the fact that $(A − λ_iI)$ is symmetric for real $λ_i$?

Comment: The point is that by hypothesis, $w=(A-\lambda_iI)v\ne 0$, so in particular $w^*w$ must be nonzero.

Comment: Remarkably the question does not ever say "real" or "complex", and without that it just doesn't makes sense. If you don't say "real", then symmetric matrices need not be diagonalisable (take $\binom{1~\phantom+\mathbf i}{\mathbf i~-1}$). But if you don't say "complex", then absence of eigenvalues with multiplicity does not imply being diagonalisable. I cannot see any merit in this line of reasoning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To flesh out my comment: that text is just wrong because it fails to say *real* symmetric matrix. A similar result does hold for Hermitian (complex) matrices, of which real symmetric matrices are a special case (since complex conjugation does not change real matrices); one *could* prove the result for real symmetric matrices by deducing it from the more general result for Hermitian matrices (and this could be derived from an even more general result for normal matrices if one likes), but one needs to state clearly what one is doing.

So a proof for Hermitian matrices is possible, for instance as follows. Eigenvalues of such matrices must be real since if $v$ is an eigenvector for$~\lambda$ then
$$
  \lambda\left\|v\right\|=\langle v\mid Av\rangle=\langle Av\mid v\rangle
 =\overline\lambda\left\|v\right\|
$$
(wth the middle equality because $A$ is Hermitian; here $\langle\cdot\mid\cdot\rangle$ is the complex inner product, linear on the right),
and $\left\|v\right\|\neq0$. A linear operator on a complex vector space of finite nonzero dimension always has at least one eigenvalue (and hence eigenvectors), so if one can find a *stable* complementary subspace to the $1$-dimensional space generated by an eigenvector$~v$, the diagonalisability will follow by induction on the dimension (restricting to such a complement one gets a linear operator on a lower dimensional space). But one has this for a Hermitian operator: if $w$ is a vector orthogonal to such an eigenvector $v$, then
$$
  \langle v\mid Aw\rangle = \langle Av\mid w\rangle
= \overline\lambda\langle v\mid w\rangle = 0
$$
so $Aw$ is again orthogonal to $v$.

I prefer this to trying to rule out generalised eigenvectors that are not eigenvectors as you text tries to do (not very successfully, since there is at least a typo of a missing $v$, and even when corrected as in the question the argument is not very clear). Once one has eigenvectors for real eigenvalues, repeated restriction to the orthogonal complements will give a basis of eigenvectors explicitly; there is no need to use generalised eigenspaces at all.